# I am getting the error message java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "" and I am not sure why and how to fix it

Tags: java, runtime-error

I am pretty new to Java and I am doing this project. I keep getting the following error message while I click a jButton (submitButton) in the runtime, and I am not sure why as it is not telling which line the problem is at.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

Below is my code, I was wondering if anybody could help? Maybe help me find the error, or tell me what the error message means. Thank you!

```
private void submitButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        String fullName = nameText.getText();
        String email = emailText.getText();
        String address = addressText.getText();
        String phoneNumber = phoneText.getText();
        // sets either true or false to membershipSelected if a plan is selected
        boolean membershipSelected = standardMembership.isSelected() || silverMembership.isSelected() || goldMembership.isSelected();
        double total = 0;
        
        // checks if the text entered in phone number text field can be parsed to an integer
        // this is only possible if it is a number, if it is a string, then error pop-up appears
        try {
            int phone = Integer.parseInt(phoneText.getText());
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(keepStrongMain.this, "This is not a valid phone number, please try again!");
        }

        // checks if email text field does not contain "@" or a domain
        if(!email.contains("@") || !email.contains(".com") && !email.contains(".de") && !email.contains(".co.uk")){
            javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(keepStrongMain.this, "This is not a valid email address, please try again!");
        }
        else {
            CardLayout card =(CardLayout)mainPanel.getLayout();
                card.show(mainPanel, "card3");
        }
        
        // checks if length of phone number is 11, if not shows error pop-up
        int phoneLength = Integer.parseInt(phoneText.getText());
        if(phoneLength != 11){
            javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(keepStrongMain.this, "This phone number is not long enough, please try again!");
        }
        else {
            CardLayout card =(CardLayout)mainPanel.getLayout();
                card.show(mainPanel, "card3");
        }
        
        // checks if a plan is selected, if not shows error pop-up
        if(membershipSelected){
            CardLayout card =(CardLayout)mainPanel.getLayout();
                card.show(mainPanel, "card3");
        }
        else {
            javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(keepStrongMain.this, "Please select a membership!");
        }
        
        // sets the final overview to an empty string that can be added to with selections later
        String overview = "";
        if (standardMembership.isSelected()){
            overview = overview + " " + standardMembership.getText() + '\n';
            total = 200;
        }
        if (silverMembership.isSelected()){
            overview = overview + " " + silverMembership.getText() + '\n';
            total = 450;
        }
        if (goldMembership.isSelected()){
            overview = overview + " " + goldMembership.getText() + '\n';
            total = 600;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The empty string is not a valid number.

Comment: After you catch the exception from `Integer.parseInt(phoneText.getText())`, you let your method continue until it gets to `Integer.parseInt(phoneText.getText())`, which will throw an exception that you don't catch this time.

Comment: >> int phoneLength = Integer.parseInt(phoneText.getText()); <<
is the number itself. The length would be 
>> int phoneLength = phoneText.getText().length; <<
and this you might check before you parse  the text.

Answer (score 0):

You have two places where you perform `Integer.parseInt(phoneText.getText());`

At the first time, the parsing is surrounded by a `try-catch` block and that handles the `NumberFormatException` that would be thrown in case `phoneText.getText()` is empty or not a number.

The second time, the parsing is not surrounded by any `try-catch`. This time the `NumberFormatException` thrown is unhandled and hence you are seeing the Exception.

You should ideally parse the `phoneText.getText()` once and have your conditions modified accordingly.